# How to insert spring form tag in jquery mRender

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc, datatables

I have a table in a Spring form and the first column is a checkbox for each line of my table.
I want to insert spring form:checkbox, but variable are not replaced with the value.
There is my example:

```
"aoColumns" : [ {
                            "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
                                if(full.eStatus!="REMOVED"){
                                    var identifier=full.identifier;
                                return '<form:checkbox path="userIdsToDelete" value="' + identifier + '" onchange="toggleCheckbox()"/>';
                                }
                                    return '';

                                }}, {
                            "mDataProp" : "firstName"
                        }, {
                            "mDataProp" : "lastName"
                        }, {
                            "mDataProp" : "email"
                        }, {
                            "mDataProp" : "staffNumber"
                        }, {
                            "mDataProp" : "enrollementTypeName" ,  "bVisible" : '${!enrollmentTypePage}'
                        }, {
                            "mDataProp" : "organizationTitle",  "bVisible" : '${allView}' 
                        }, {
                            "mDataProp" : "status"
                        } ]
```

When I inspect the checkBox element : `<input id="userIdsToDelete1" name="userIdsToDelete" onchange="toggleCheckbox()" type="checkbox" value="' + identifier + '">`

However, when I put in "mRender" a html input without spring form tag , it replace well my identifier Variable.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by adding input html without using spring Tag Form.

```
"aoColumns" : [ {
                            "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
                                if(full.eStatus!="REMOVED"){

                                    var identifier=full.identifier;
                                    var checkBox='<input name="userIdsToDelete" onchange="toggleCheckbox()" type="checkbox" value="'+identifier+'">'+
                                       '<input type="hidden" name="_userIdsToDelete" value="on">';

                                return checkBox ;


                                }

                              return '';

                                }}, {
                            "mDataProp" : "firstName"
                        }, {
                            "mDataProp" : "lastName"
                        }, {
                            "mDataProp" : "email"
                        }, {
                            "mDataProp" : "staffNumber"
                        }, {
                            "mDataProp" : "enrollementTypeName" ,  "bVisible" : '${!enrollmentTypePage}'
                        }, {
                            "mDataProp" : "organizationTitle",  "bVisible" : '${allView}' 
                        }, {
                            "mDataProp" : "status"
                        } ]
```